# Android Studio, Flutter: Emulator not found in View -> Tool windows

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

The `Emulator` window within the android studio, and `Device file Explorer` are not available in Android studio. What could be the reason? I have enabled it in the settings.

Comment: Have you tried restarting android studio?

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar Yes, I also tried flutter clean, flutter doctor. But Everything is fine. The issue exists for flutter project as well as the android project.

Comment: Press ctrl+shift+a and search for the emulator. See if that works

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar I tried it , but it didnt help

Comment: That's weird. Invalidate cache and check you Event Log as well if it's saying configure then configure it.

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar That too doesn't work. This issue already exists in other stack overflow questions.

Comment: Open File > Project Structure, can u, first of all, see the expected project structure and secondly make sure there are 2 modules in module section on <project_name> and other <project_name>_android

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways to solve this problem temporarily until the bug is fixed by experts:

1. Create **new project in other IDE's** and return back to `android studio` after a successful run.
2. *This method is preferred*:

   **Create flutter project through terminal**. To create to new flutter project
   through `terminal`, run the following command in `Android Studio terminal` :

> ```
>    cd C:\Users\asus\AndroidStudioProjects
>
>    flutter create project_name
>
>    cd project_name
>
>    flutter run
> ```

Then open this project from File->Open.

After these steps I was able to see `Emulator` in the `SideBar`